# Undefined variable: user_id

Tags: php, laravel

I started a small project using Laravel and i try to pass a user_id variable from my controller to my view, but i get an error message :

```
Undefined variable: user_id
```

This is my controller function :

```
public function modals(Request $request){

    return view("modals.member", ["user_id" => 11]);
}
```

And this is my view page :

```
<strong>{{ $user_id }}</strong>
```

What wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... perhaps there is another route handler that returns this same view that is getting hit?

Comment: Yes you alright it was another route perfect man

Answer (score 1):

You need to use compact() as follows:

```
  public function modals(Request $request){
     $user_id=11;
     return view("modals.member",compact('user_id'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the manual from Wordpress below, and correct call is, this does set even with zero value:

```
isset( $user->ID )
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/

This code below adds user 0 to the handle if nothing exists:

```
? (int) $user->ID : 0
```

User manual says this code which is more correct:

```
( isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 0 );
```